# MathJax has ceased rendering on my system

Tags: support, math-display

Between yesterday and today MathJax (and edit previews) have ceased working. I have not updated my browser in that time, nor have I changed my browser settings. Is there a troubleshooting page to understand how to fix this this? The site is unpleasant to read without MathJax.

Comment: It might be something related to [the thing discussed here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26166/should-math-se-support-mathjax-on-its-own-server). Is it possible you're blocking cdnjs.cloudflare.com? If you're using NoScript then there's some advice in the comments about how to enable MathJax without whitelisting the whole of cdnjs.cloudflare.com . If you are using noscript you can check if this is the issue by temporarily enabling cloudflare.com and seeing if the mathematics renders (you can then disable again).  I use NoScript so I presume this will be an issue for me soon.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your browser? (I guess you have but just to check.) If so, try clearing browser's cache and restarting again.

Comment: There are some hints on the MathJax pages http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/faq.html which also links to how to clear your cache (which was news to me, perhaps not to you).

Comment: @Glen_b That was **exactly** it! Please make an answer, so I can accept. :)

Comment: @amoeba Yes. And my OS.

Comment: @mdewey Not  cache issue for me, but thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible cause of the problem.

MathJax.org have paid to host a [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN) to make it easier for people to host MathJax pages (at cdn.mathjax.org). However, cloudflare have increased the cost of doing this to them and MathJax have decided to focus their resources on development.

Consequently, as recommended by MathJax and as described in [this math.SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26166/should-math-se-support-mathjax-on-its-own-server), the hosting of math.SE's MathJax libraries have moved 
to cdnjs.cloudflare.com (which cdnjs pay cloudflare for)

If for any reason you're blocking cdnjs.cloudflare.com (or likely cloudflare.com more broadly) then MathJax might stop working for you on math or here on CV (along with [other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) that use MathJax).

If you're using NoScript (for example), blocking cloudflare.com would be the default action. There's some advice in the comments at the linked math.SE page about how to enable MathJax without whitelisting the whole of cdnjs.cloudflare.com :

> For NoScript, I find that one can whitelist https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com and add an ABE rule Site https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/* Anonymize Site cdnjs.cloudflare.com Deny (with line breaks before uppercase letters)

There's also advice for users of UBlock Origin and other discussion you may care to read there.

If you are using NoScript you could check if this is the issue by *temporarily enabling* cloudflare.com (it should show up in the list if you check the NoScript menu while reading this page - hover over the NoScript icon in your browser, which is a bold S with a small red circle and diagonal line) and seeing if the mathematics renders (you can then disable again the same way, and try to implement the safer-in-the-long-term advice in the comments at the math.SE post).